# LINQ on Identity not working after upgrading to 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have upgraded an asp.netcore 2.x web application, to 3.0 and I have a very weird behaviour with a LINQ query to Identity users: If I run the Linq query to get an Identity user based on the username the result is null, but if I loop over the users an apply the condition manually it works.

The application is setup with 'individual user' accounts

I have tried some variation on the Linq query but they all return null. If I check the '_Context.Users' results view in visualstudio the users are in there.

Consider the following code, where _Context is my ApplicationDBContext and name is the username of the user I want to get. (and yes the string is a correct user name)

```
 var user = _Context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault();
//var u2 = (from u in _Context.Users where u.UserName.Equals(name) select u).FirstOrDefault();
//var u3 =  _Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(name);

//at this point user should not be null, but it is
if (user == null)
{
    var users = _Context.Users;
    foreach (var u in users)
    {
        if (u.UserName.Equals(name))
        {
            //if the linq does not work, we should not get here but we do
            user = u;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the result of the Queries and the loop should be the same but they are not. Using the loop is a workaround but I suspect it to be far less efficient than a database query.
'm also not confident about deploying my application to Azure with these kind of weird things going on (the reasons I've updated is because deploy to azure failed because of some verion conflicts).

I am not 100% sure that this has got to do with 3.0 but the query worked before the upgrade. Authentication itself seems to be working correctly, I can login with any user.

Comment: Well described, only I think the comment should read `//if the linq worked, then we should not get here but we do`. I suggest to **[edit]** the question if I'm right.

Comment: @PeterB I disagree, as this is the core of the question, if the linq query does not return a result, why does the loop?

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now - `//if the Equals in linq finds no match, then Equals here should also find no match but it does`. I can only think that the two Equals are *not* doing the same (anymore), the Linq Equals runs in the database as SQL and probably it compares differently in SQL vs how .NET compares.

Comment: Is it there any special charactors in `UserName` from database? like `\t,\n`or space? Is database using special language, which you have to specify `CompareOptions` for `Equals`?

Comment: @PeterB I was thinking the same thing, its weird though usually linq to object is more restrictive because of case sensitivity,  but

Comment: @Dongdong,Not really there is a '/' in some of the usernames though (which has its reasons). The real implementation also has an 'EqualsIgnoreCase' on both the linq and the fallback (which I left out for simplicity) here. All characters are in the latin characterset for now...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 'StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase' parameter which was omitted from the sample code (to make it more readable) was causing the issue. With this parameter the generated query was

```
SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[Email], ...., [a].[UserName]  FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]  WHERE CAST(0 AS bit) = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

Clearly this query will never have any results.

If casing is important it works by changing the linq where to `u.UserName.ToLower() == name.ToLower()` but as SQL is case insensitive by default just using `name.Equals(u.UserName)` also works.